# Maybe someone knows a simple algorithm for finding the number of '0' elements that are between '1' elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need a simple algorithm to find the number of occurrences of 0 between 1 in an array, for example, after performing certain operations on these arrays:

```
var mas1 = [0,1,0,0,1]
var mas2 = [1,0,0,0,1]
var mas3 = [0,1,0,1,0]
var mas4 = [0,0,0,0,1]
var mas4 = [1,0,1,0,1]
```

We have to get:

```
result = 2
result = 3
result = 1
result = 0
result = 2
```

We can have any number of 1's or 0's in an unlimited array
Any ideas?

Comment: How would you do this with a pencil and a piece of paper?

Comment: Use `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` to get the indexes of the first and last `1` in the array. Then just subtract them to get the number of `0`. This assumes there's at most 2 `1` in the array, and the array only contains 0 and 1

Comment: What if 1,0,1,0,1 ?

Comment: we need return 2

Comment: I would use some sort of state-full iteration with a state variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continuously use `indexOf` to find the next `1` while accumulating the size of ranges in between consecutive ones.

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1];
let count = 0;
for(let i = arr.indexOf(1); i != -1; ){
    const next = arr.indexOf(1, i + 1);
    if (next !== -1) count += next - i - 1;
    i = next;
}
console.log(count);
```